# How to mark parts of the total amount in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, nlp, distribution

I am trying to create a simple histogram with pythons matplotlib.

It's about the distribution of comment lengths. I have several thousand comments, and I already have the following code:

```
x = [60, 55, 2, 30, ..., 190]

plt.hist(x, bins=100)
plt.xlim(0,150)
plt.grid(axis="x")
plt.title("Distribution of Comment Lengths")
plt.xlabel("Tokens/Comment")
plt.ylabel("Amount of Comments")
plt.show()
```

What I would like to implement is a way to show by which point I have passed 50% of all Tokens (or 33% and 66%, or 25%, 50% and 75%). I am imagining a vertical line that separates the distribution in two halves, with an equal amount of Tokens on both sides.

Does matplotlib give the opportunity to achieve this easily?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the x-value corresponding to `p%` of all comments, just sort the list of values and then index it at `p%` of the total length. You could add vertical lines at these positions, and add a second x-axis to label them.

To get the x-value corresponding to `p%` of all tokens, find where the element with value `p% of the sum of all the x's` is positioned in the array with the cumulative sum of the sorted list. Use that position to index the sorted list of values.

Here is some code to show how it could work.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create some random data to test, convert to a regular Python list to be similar to the question
x = list(np.abs(np.random.normal(85, 30, 2000)))
wanted_percentiles = [5, 10, 25, 33, 50, 66, 75, 90, 95]
sx = np.array(x)
sx.sort()
cx = sx.cumsum()

percentile_sx = [sx[int(len(x) * p / 100)] for p in wanted_percentiles]
percentile_cx = [sx[cx.searchsorted(cx[-1] * p / 100)] for p in wanted_percentiles]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
for ax, percentile, color, title in zip(axes, [percentile_sx, percentile_cx],
                                 ['crimson', 'limegreen'], ['Comments Percentile', 'Tokens Percentile']):
    ax.hist(x, bins=20)
    for xp in percentile:
        ax.axvline(xp, color=color)
    ax2 = ax.twiny()

    ax.set_xlim(0, 150)
    ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())  # both axes need exactly the same limits
    ax2.set_xticks(percentile)  # use the xs corresponding to the percentiles as tick positions
    ax2.set_xticklabels(wanted_percentiles, color=color) # use the percentiles to label the ticks
    ax.set_title("Distr. of Comment Lengths, " + title)
    ax.set_xlabel("Comments binned via number of tokens")
    ax.set_ylabel("Amount of Comments")
plt.show()
```

At the left the plot with 100 bins, at the right how it would look with 20 bins:

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you very much! But I think your code marks the percentiles of the amount of comments, if every comment is treated as one singular data point. I am actually looking for the amount of tokens that would be covered if I just take the comments from inside this percentile. But after you've showed me how to mark the percentiles this way, I think I can come up with the rest.